# C# file upload via multipartform extremely slow on large files

Tags: c#, post, httpclient, multipartform-data

What is wrong with below?  It's taking roughly 2.5 hours to upload a 2gb file.  Via a web based client it's taking 10 minutes to do the same thing.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I speed this up?  Thanks.

```
public static async Task UploadFile(string path)
{

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    httpClient.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;

    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);

    HttpResponseMessage m = new HttpResponseMessage();

    form.Add(streamContent, path.Substring(0, path.Length-4), path);

    try
    {
        m = await httpClient.PostAsync(@"https://xxxxx/api/DataObjects/addAFile?access_token=" + Token, form);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to Post Upload File Request:\n" + @"https://xxxxx/api/DataObjects/addAFile?access_token=" + Token + "\nMessage: " + ex.Message);
    }
    httpClient.Dispose();
}
```

Is this a memory issue?  A problem encoding the file into a stream?

Comment: The code itself looks ok. Why is it slow no one can say without some investigation. There are simply too many variables. It could be network latency between the source and destination. It could be throttling on the network (source and/or destination), it could be hardware issues itself (bad NIC on dest or source), it could be disk I/O issues on the destination or source, etc....

Comment: @Igor a web based client (written in javascript) using the **same** API alongside the **same** computer has an insane speed up compared to above.  Seems to me this rules out network latency, throttling, NIC, and I/O on the destination.

Comment: In a client, messages sent to server are **HttpRequestMessage** (HttpResponseMessage are generated in the server to respond to client request).

Comment: Try to read all file-bytes into a MemoryStream instead of using FileStream. Just to see if it has any effect.

Comment: I would also Dispose disposable objects, explictly (using-statement for instance - form, fileStream). In case garbage collection is to slow to free up memory. If you upload with high frequency, then file IO might become a bottleneck